# Segmentation Fault with sprintf and fwrite(); program only works with valgrind

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when running my program that only allows me to print out 1 broken image. However, when I run the program with valgrind it prints out 49 of the 50 photos, and the only photo not working is the last one.

After running help50 valgrind with the program, I realized there is a segmentation fault with sprintf, as well as something possibly wrong with the fwrite() towards the end of the program. Any clarification would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check you're actually recovering a file.
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid entry.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Open file for reading.
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Set 1st photo as jpg.001.
    int counter = 1;

    // Check if bytes are jpg. signatures.
    for (int n = 0; counter < 51; n = n + 512)
    {
        // Sets an array to contain 4 values and directs pointer to start from nth value each time.
        unsigned char array[512];
        fseek(file, n, SEEK_SET);
        fread(array, 1, 512, file); // if EOF, won't have 512 to write into!!!

        // Declare character array jpg.
        char* jpg_name;

        // While 1st 4 bytes are jpg signature.
        if (array[0] == 0xff && array[1] == 0xd8 && array[2] == 0xff && (array[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // Convert integer to string and store into jpg character array. Increment image number.
            jpg_name = malloc(4*sizeof(char));
            sprintf(jpg_name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            counter++;

            // Open images file to write into,allocate memory to jpg file to write into, write 512 bytes from array into image file.
            FILE *images = fopen(jpg_name, "a");
            fwrite(array, 1, 512, images);

            // Free file memory?
            free(jpg_name);
            fclose(images);
        }
        else // If 1st 4 bytes aren't jpg signature.
        {
            // Add bytes to existing image (if present), otherwise repeat loop.
            if (counter > 1)
            {
                FILE *images = fopen(jpg_name, "a");
                fwrite(array, 1, 512, images); // SEGMENTATION FAULT; need to detect end of file.
                fclose(images);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sprintf(jpg_name, "%03i.jpg", counter);` is too much for a 4-byte buffer which needs at least 8.  Try `malloc(40)` instead.

Comment: `FILE *images = fopen(jpg_name, "a");` in `else` block does not have a valid `jpg_name`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for getting back to me. Do you mind explaining why I would need 8-bytes instead? Is it because 000.jpg is 7, plus the null terminator means I need 8?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't understand what you mean by not having a valid jpg_name, because it is printing my photos correctly with correct file names too, I'm just getting a memory leak.

Comment: General hint: you always, always need to check if `fopen` succeeds. There is absolutely no excuse not doing so.

Comment: @ckwan: `jpg_name` is malloced and freed within the `if` block, so any access to it in the `else` block is either using an uninitialized pointer or accessing memory that has been freed.  Both are bad.  A general principle about C is that since many sorts of bugs can yield behavior that sometimes appears correct, saying "my program works correctly" does not prove that it actually *is* correct.

Comment: @NateEldredge understood. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: OT:  regarding: `printf("Invalid entry.\n");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the wrong number of command line parameters have been entered by the user. Then need to output a USAGE message, similar to:  `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s imageFile\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `jpg_name = malloc(4*sizeof(char));`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value.  If the call to `malloc()` fails (==NULL) then output a error message to `stderr`.  Also, since this is a C library function, also output (to `stderr`) the text reason for the failure:  Suggest: `perror( "malloc failed" ); then cleanup then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `fread(array, 1, 512, file);`  Always check the returned value (in this case expect the returned value to be the third parameter `512`)

Comment: OT: regarding: `fwrite(array, 1, 512, images);`  Always check the returned value (in this case expect the returned value to be the third parameter `512`)

Comment: regarding: `fseek(file, n, SEEK_SET);`  1) the 'n' is expected to be a 'long int'  2) 'n' is the number of bytes (not the number of images) from the beginning of the file.  3)  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  a returned value of 0 indicates success.

Comment: regarding: `jpg_name = malloc(4*sizeof(char));` 1) why malloc()?  you know the number of bytes needed is 8 for all the output file names.  Suggest:  'char jpg_name[9];`  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) the output of the statement: `sprintf(jpg_name, "%03i.jpg", counter);` will always be 8 characters (as long as 'counter' is less than 100) so allocating only 4 characters will result in a buffer overflow and undefined behavior

Comment: Suggest: do not close the current output file until the beginning of the next image is found (or EOF is encountered on the input file)

Comment: regarding: `return 0;`  immediately after the check of `argc` == 2, is saying the wrong thing.  a returned value of 0 (typically) means success. and this code pathe was not 'success'.  Suggest `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");`  An image file is NOT an ascii file, but rather a binary file.  suggest: `FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");` This will not maje a difference under Linux, but will with other OSs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

caveat: without your input file, I cannot fully test this proposed code.

caveat: the proposed code expects the first line of the input file to contain a 'header' for the first .jpg image

caveat: the proposed code expects each image to be a multiple of 512 bytes

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality (as far as tested)
3. properly checks for I/O errors
4. properly opens files in binary mode (although Linux won't care)
5. assumes that each image will be a multiple of 512 bytes
6. properly differentiates between error exits and success exits
7. does not include header files those contents are not used

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// #include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check the user entered a command line parameter for a input file name
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s inputFileName\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // Open file for reading.
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        perror( "fopen for input file failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // Set 1st photo as jpg.001.
    // Declare character array jpg.
    char jpg_name[10];
    FILE *images = NULL;
    
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 51;  )
    {
        unsigned char array[512];
        ssize_t bytesRead;
        if( (bytesRead = fread(array, 1, 512, file) != 512 ) )
        {
            perror( "fread failed" );
            fclose( images );
            fclose( file );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // if 1st 4 bytes are jpg signature.
        if (    array[0] == 0xff 
            &&  array[1] == 0xd8 
            &&  array[2] == 0xff 
            && (array[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if( images )
            {
                fclose( images );
                images = NULL;
                counter++;
            }
            
            sprintf(jpg_name, "%03i.jpg", counter+1);

            images = fopen(jpg_name, "wb");
            if( ! images )
            {
                perror( "fopen for output file failed" );
                fclose( file );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
        }
        
        // Add bytes to current output image
        if( fwrite(array, 1, 512, images) != 512 )
        {
            perror( "fwrite failed" );
            fclose( images );
            fclose( file );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    
    fclose( images );
    fclose( file );
}
```